# How to avoid having different methods looping the same list?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a class that is mapped from a xml. To make it simple, let's imagine this class is something like:

```
class Employee implements EmployeeIF {
    Map<AttributeIF,Object> attribute = new HashMap<>();
    @Override
    public Map<AttributeIF,Object> getAttributes() { return attribute; }
}
```

This is something I cannot change.

Now, the existing code is full of methods like:

```
public int getSalary(EmployeeIF employee) {
    for(Entry<AttributeIF,Object> entry : employee.getAttributes()) {
        if(entry.getKey().getName().equals("salary")) return (Integer)entry.getValue();
    }
    return 0;
}

public int getAddress(EmployeeIF employee) {
    for(Entry<AttributeIF,Object> entry : employee.getAttributes()) {
        if(entry.getKey().getName().equals("address")) return (String)entry.getValue();
    }
    return "";
}
```

... and so on. Surely you got the idea.

I need to include a new method to return a new attribute from the employee, but as I feel this is horrible to mantain, I refuse to just add a new method there.
I am thinking on using the action pattern to somehow avoiding at least repeating againg and again the for loop but I have to say that I cannot find a smart solution for this.

What would be your choices?

Thanks,
Dani.

P.D Yes I tried something like

```
private Object getAttribute(EmployeeIF employee, String attribute)
```

Comment: You are working on a `Map`, why don´t you make use of it´s key and get the value directly from the key?

Comment: I cannot change the class AttributeIF, which is the key of the map. This is autogenerated as well.

Comment: You have to override equal() method in Employee class. Then you can use map.get() call.

Comment: Yup thats what I posted as a comment to deleted answer. Override equal of class which you are using as key. Use name field in equals. But you must make sure that things don't impact your other functionality

Comment: What is `AttributeIF` ? Is it a Object or just a String..?

Comment: If you have a sensible implementation of `AttributeIF` with a `equals()` method that make sense, you can just construct it with the give `name` and get the value from the map. Otherwise, Consider lazy initialization i.e. the first time you need the map, you build it into a `Map<String, Object>` so you put the `name` as the key.

BTW, looks like typical OTT design of the `AttributeIF` class.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tiny example how you could get, based on a object as key that you don´t have, the value.

```
public class TestObject {
    public String val;

    public TestObject(String val) {
        this.val = val;
    }

    public static TestObject createDummy(String val) {
        return new TestObject(val);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) return true;
        if (!(obj instanceof TestObject)) return false;
        return ((TestObject)obj).val.equals(this.val);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        System.out.println("THIS ONE IS IMPORTANT");
        return val.hashCode();
    }
}

public class TestMap {
    public Map<TestObject, String> map = new HashMap<>();

    public String get(String keyVal) {
        return map.get(TestObject.createDummy(keyVal));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestMap map = new TestMap();
        TestObject o1 = new TestObject("A");
        map.map.put(o1,"B");
        TestObject o2 = new TestObject("B");
        map.map.put(o2,"C");
        TestObject o3 = new TestObject("C");
        map.map.put(o3,"D");
        System.out.println(map.get("B"));
    }
}
```

The Key to it, is to override `equals` and `hashCode` in your `AttributeIF` class. So in case you are passing a dummy object of they `AttributeIF` you do want to have your map needs to identify this dummy object to be equal with the instance of an theoretcly "equal" key object instance inside your `Map`.